# persist() is not available in React18, how can I store synthetic event value to reuse in a second event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, persist

I´m working with React18. 1- I have a  calling a synthetic event that will pass the value to a function that stores this value in a variable "myQuery".

2- Then, this function call one async function which will fetch data and render a list of photos (page 1) with the value of the synthetic event value as a dynamic query.

3- After selecting an option and rendering a list of photos, I click a button that will call a function which changes the page of the list using the same query (that prior synthetic event value)

PROBLEM: but this time the query is empty because the synthetic event value no longer exist, and I cannot use persist() in ReactJS18

```
 let myQuery;
    let pages = page;
    let images_per_page = 40;
    let orientation = "landscape";

    async function FetchHandler(){
        setPage(page+1);
        let data;
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=${myQuery}&orientation=${orientation}&page=${pages}&per_page=${images_per_page}&client_id=9GaoQc3xxCZ7FBAyP7eQ3kj67sH7lt5-2BiOR5_uPd8`);
        if(response.ok){
            data = await response.json();
            setFetchData(data);
        }
    }

    const sessionHandler=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        e.persist();
        console.log(e.target.value);
        myQuery = e.target.value;
        FetchHandler();
    }

    const clickHandler=()=>{
        console.log(myQuery)
        FetchHandler()
    }

    return(
        <div className="ideas-container">
            <h1>Get inspired by some ideas from google</h1>
            <h5>Share the idea with us and we can make just like you want</h5>
            <select onChange={(e)=>sessionHandler(e)}>
                {
                    objData.map((option)=>(
                        <option key={option.id}>{option.name}</option>
                    ))
                }
            </select>    
            <div className="ideaDetails-container">
                {
                    
                    fetchData &&
                        fetchData.results.map((obj,index)=>{
                            return(
                                <li key={index}>
                                    <IdeaDetails obj={obj}/>
                                </li>
                            )
                        })
                }                
            </div>  

            <button>Previou</button><button onClick={clickHandler}>Next</button>
            <Outlet context={objData}/>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Ideas;
```

1- I tried to store this event in the myQuery variable to reuse it, but as synthetic event it nullifies the value after used.

```
const sessionHandler=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        e.persist();
        console.log(e.target.value);
        myQuery = e.target.value;
```

2- I tried to use persist() but it is not available in React18. (React documentation: https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#react-event-object-methods)

```
const sessionHandler=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        e.persist();
        console.log(e.target.value);
        myQuery = e.target.value;
```

3- I also tried useState to store this value (which works) but React hooks a called first, but it cannot the value cannot be holded before the user click on the  to choose the option.

What other approach can I try?